# Maximum Limit - List the products from Google Shopping Content API

Tags: php, google-apis-explorer, google-content-api

I am using below code for getting list of products from Google Shopping content API.

```
   $products = $service->products->listProducts($merchantId,
                   array('pageToken' => $nextPageToken,
                         'maxResults' => 100));
```

I am getting 100 products for each API request because of `'maxResults' => 100`

But I want to know the maximum limit of **`"maxResults"`** Parameter.

I checked the below link for this, but I didn't get maximum limit value.

https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/reference/rest/v2/products/list

Anyone know the maximum limit value.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

250 according to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/guides/order-limits#list-method)...

> The list method has the following known issues:
>
> ```
> maxResults: This field is not yet implemented, but will be available
> soon with a default of 25 results and a max value allowed of 250.
> ```